# Add attribute to an Element of xml.etree.ElementTree and make serializable to XML

Tags: python, dynamic, attr

I would like to add an attribute to some instance of `Element` from `xml.etree.ElementTree` in order to store satellite data such as `numpy.ndarray` into some tree's nodes. Is that possible, because the object does not expose `__dict__` and `__slot__`?

I know that I can use `get`/`set` methods to fill the node attribute, but if it holds other objects than `str`, it cannot be serialized as XML.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "latexer.py", line 576, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "latexer.py", line 565, in main
    r.dump(**k)
  File "latexer.py", line 406, in dump
    code = self.__fileFormats[ufformat]()
  File "latexer.py", line 416, in getXML
    rawstr = ET.tostring(self._document, encoding='utf-8', method='xml')
  File "C:\Python33\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1171, in tostring
    ElementTree(element).write(stream, encoding, method=method)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 828, in write
    serialize(write, self._root, qnames, namespaces)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 990, in _serialize_xml
    _serialize_xml(write, e, qnames, None)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 990, in _serialize_xml
    _serialize_xml(write, e, qnames, None)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 990, in _serialize_xml
    _serialize_xml(write, e, qnames, None)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 983, in _serialize_xml
    v = _escape_attrib(v)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1139, in _escape_attrib
    _raise_serialization_error(text)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1105, in _raise_serialization_error
    "cannot serialize %r (type %s)" % (text, type(text).__name__)
TypeError: cannot serialize 1 (type int)
```

Is there a way to add attribute such `bool` or `integer` and then serialize it to XML?

Comment: Have you tried `https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element` property `attrib`?

Comment: @AnthonyKong Thank you for underlining it, I figured somehow (perhaps the XML dark side) that it could be only text stored in this dictionary.

Comment: @AnthonyKong I have edited my question, because I am still stuck at some point.

Answer (score 0):

After reading some other posts about this problem, I accepted that there is no direct, elegant solution to this problem, because - for good reasons - nat all objects can be casted into string implicitly.

Then, I found an intermediate way. The technique consists to pickle hexlified object. When I want to access it just invoke the reverse process.

I know that it is not efficient in terms of data storage and computation overhead, but it works and solved my problem, because my tree need to be dumped into XML and reopened after.

The code looks like:

```
def _fillNode(self, node, text=None, **kwargs):
    """Fill a given node with text and arguments (serialized if non string) from kwargs"""
    node.text = text
    for (k, v) in kwargs.items():
        # Append string as this:
        if isinstance(v, str):
            node.set(k, v)
        # If not a string pickle, hexlify and encode: 
        else:
            node.set(k, binascii.hexlify(pickle.dumps(v)).decode())
    return node

def _getAttribute(self, node, key, default=None):
    """Get node attribute as string but try first to deserialize it"""
    # Try to recover string formated data:
    value = node.get(key)
    if value:
        try:
            # try to decode, unhexlify and unpickle:
            return pickle.loads(binascii.unhexlify(value.encode()))
        except:
            # If not return as this
            return value
    else:
        return default
```